# Add tuple if id in a comma separated cell

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle 11g, any help would be great

I have a table as follows

```
IDS
-----------
1
1,2
1,2,4
1,2,5
1,2,6
1,3,7
1,3,8
1,3,9
```

I need to return all row that contain a given value

so for a value of 2 the following would be returned

```
1,2
1,2,4
1,2,5
1,2,6
```

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

While I wouldn't recommend storing comma separated lists, here's one option using `concat` with `like`:

```
select * 
from yourtable
where concat(concat(',', ids), ',') like '%,2,%'
```

Edit -- Since you are using `oracle`, you'd need to use multiple `concat` statements...

Answer (score 1):

Storing ids in a comma-separated list is a bad idea for many reasons:

- SQL does not have very good string functions (although Oracle is better than most).
- Storing numeric ids as strings is a bad idea.
- Storing multiple values in a single column is a bad idea.
- Not declaring foreign key relationships is a bad idea.
- SQL has a great structure for storing lists; it is called a table (a *junction* table, in this case).
- Oracle has specialized constructs such as nested tables that are more appropriate.

That said, sometimes we are stuck with other peoples bad design decisions.  You can use `like`:

```
select t* 
from t
where ',' || ids || ',' like '%,2,%';
```

Comment: I understand adding an answer an hour after the correct (and identical) solution was posted by another forum participant; your answer gives more detail on why the OP's database design is suboptimal. However, I do not understand the need to post the code, which sgeddes had already posted.

Comment: @mathguy . . . If you look at the revision history, you'll see that the other answer was syntactically incorrect for Oracle when I wrote this answer.

Comment: I saw that too. That deserves a comment on the other answer, not a hijacking.